# Understanding why an element mapped to a generator has finite order

Tags: group-theory, exact-sequence

Here is the setup of a problem in group theory I can trying to solve. $G$ is a group, and there is a short exact sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2 \rightarrow G \rightarrow^{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/k \rightarrow 0. 
$$
Suppose that $\varphi(g) = 1$ for $g \in G$. Then the order of $g$ is either $k$ or $2k$.

The solution that I've read makes sense to me, but seems to include an implicit assumption that $g$ has finite order. This is what I'm able to understand, with the step I find problematic bolded. (I'm using multiplicative notation in $\mathbb{Z}/k$, but I acknowledge this is non-standard since the group is abelian. This is a bit easier for me to see understand some of the steps.)

> **Let $n = |g|$ in $G$.** Then $g^n = e$, so $\phi(g^n) = \varphi(g)^n = 1^n = 0$. So the order of $1$ divides $n$. That is, $k$ divides $n$ since $1$ has order $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}/k$. The existence of the aforementioned short exact sequence implies that $G$ contains a normal subgroup $K$ with $K \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$ and that $G/K \cong \mathbb{Z}/k$. So $|G/K| = |\mathbb{Z}/k| = k$. As $K \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$, $|K| = 2$. **So by Lagrange's theorem,**
> $$
> |G/K| = \frac{|G|}{|K|} = \frac{|G|}{2} = k,
> $$
> so $|G| = 2k$. As $g \in G$, $|g|$ divides $2k$. So $|g|$ is a multiple of $k$ and a divisor of $2k$. The only options are $k$ and $2k$.

Several steps of the proof, unless I am misunderstanding them, rely on $g$ having finite order or, more generally, on $G$ being a finite group. If I knew the latter, then $g$ would certainly have finite order. I don't know how I can figure out that this must be the case. The short exact sequence definition, as I understand it, is:

- The map $f: \mathbb{Z}/2 \to G$ is injective ($\text{ker}(f) = \{0\}$)
- The map $\varphi: G \to \mathbb{Z}/k$ is surjective.
- $\text{Im}(f) = \text{ker}(\varphi)$.

This is supposed to imply that there exists a subgroup $K$ of $G$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $G/K \cong \mathbb{Z}/k$. The solution I'm reading takes this to be the kernel of $\varphi$. The kernel is certainly a normal subgroup, though I don't fully understand why $K$ must be the kernel. Is it just a convenient choice?

Comment: $G$ cannot be infinite. The short exact sequence together with Lagrange theorem implies that (note that Lagrange written as $|G|=|H|\cdot |G/H|$ is valid for all groups, even infinite). Also the kernel of $\varphi$ is equal to image of $f$ which is isomorphic to ,$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ because $f$ is injective. Everything is already written here, I'm not sure what is unclear exactly.

Comment: @ValorVaporeon, It seems to me natural in this case to consider the group $G$ additive, to avoid the nonsense of $1^n=0$.

Comment: @freakish I'm not sure I quite understand the statement that $|G| = |H| \cdot |G/H|$ holds even when $G$ is infinite. Wouldn't that just reduce to $\infty = \infty$? The interpretation might be that if $H$ is finite and $G$ is infinite, there are infinitely many left cosets of $H$, which itself makes sense.

Comment: @ValorVaporeon well, this is cardinal number arithmetic. But yes, you can think about infinities. Clearly if $H$ is finite and $G/H$ is finite then the formula implies that $G$ is finite as well. So no, it doesn't just reduce to $\infty=\infty$, there are rules involved here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your notation we have
$$
\varphi(g^k) = \varphi(g)^k = 1^k = 0,
$$
so $g^k \in \ker \varphi = \operatorname{im} f$, and then
$$
g^k=f(a)
$$
for some $a \in \Bbb Z/2$.

- If $a=0$, then $g^k = f(0) = e$ and the order of $g$ divides $k$; in particular, **the order of $g$ is finite**. As you showed in the first line, this implies that the order of $g$ is $k$.
- If $a=1$, then $g^k=f(1)$, and then $g^{2k} = f(1)^2 = f(1^2) = f(0) = e$, which implies that the order of $g$ is $k$ or $2k$.